# how to disable JIT mode while building firefox?

Tags: firefox, build, interpreter, jit

As we know that there are two modes to execute javascript in firefox:interpreter and JIT.
My question is that whether I can disable JIT while building firefox in linux,and if so,how?
Any useful suggestion will be appreciated , thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the --disable-methodjit configure option *might* work: SpiderMonkey supports it, but it's not obvious to me whether it'll propagate from the main build to the SpiderMonkey configure step.

Comment: I tried,but failed.I even tried --disable-tracejit and --disable-jit,but all of these options seem to be effectiveless.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to just use the pref to disable at runtime?

Comment: I would like to run some tests on v8 with and without JIT to compare performances. I know JIT will improve my average speed performance, but it would be nice for me to have some actual more detailed tests results as I want to work with mobile platforms.
I haven't found how to enable or disable JIT like it exists on Squirrelfish (cf. ENABLE_JIT in JavaScriptCore/wtf/Platform.h).

Comment: Sounds like just disabling with the prefs at runtime should be fine for your purposes, then...

Answer (score 0):

Building Firefox without JIT is broken. Sources do not track ENABLE_JIT & friends carefully.